# Word Order and Comparative

Tags: word-order, comparatives

Consider the different locations of the subject, adjective, and conjunction in the following sentences.

> *A boy as trim* as Bob should be a fast runner.
>
> *As trim a boy* as Bob should be a fast runner.

The second sentence sounds unusual to me, but I am not a native speaker. Is it ungrammatical or merely a literary form of the first? If the second version is grammatical, does it change the emphasis (e.g. from the adjective to the subject)?

Comment: Google Books claims 17 written instances of what I would say is the "natural" sequence: [*A woman as beautiful as her could (marry any man she wanted)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+woman+as+beautiful+as+her+could%22), but none at all for the ("poetic inversion"?) sequence [*As beautiful a woman as her could (do the same).*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+beautiful+a+woman+as+her+could%22) But I'd say they're both "grammatical".

Comment: Nowadays, you don't see "trim" being used much, it sounds a bit dated to me. I think the first sentence is definitely more idiomatic.   The second sounds a bit weird, it does sound slightly ungrammatical. You could also say *"A trim boy like Bob should be a fast runner"

Comment: There are Google Books hits for ["as beautiful a woman as"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&tbm=bks&ei=-ryvWsLnAovejgSP04vADQ&q=%22as+beautiful+a+woman+as%22&oq=%22as+beautiful+a+woman+as%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6274.8408.0.9387.10.10.0.0.0.0.127.1001.6j4.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.ZqSjfF9gto8)

Comment: They are both grammatically fine, though the first is surely more  likely.

Comment: BillJ has the truth of is and what was your own conclusion, supported by what research, please?